# Cocos2d: handling touches that start outside a CCMenu (or similar) item in a multitouch environment

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, multi-touch

I have enabled multitouch in my AppDelegate. In my game scene InputLayer I added a CCMenu with some CCMenuItemSprite used as buttons and a SneakyJostic as controller. In my input layer I enabled touch, in this way conforming to the "Standard Touch Delegate" protocol because I want to be able to evaluate some user touches outside the CCMenu and the SneakyJoystic controller.

When a user starts to touch the screen outside the area of either SneakyJoystick or CCMenu class instances when the user's finger position reaches above the menu or joystic instance the touch is not detected by instance but instead stays under the control of the touchMoved (and/or then touchEnded) method of the scene layer.

Is there a way to prevent this? I mean, **how can I get the menu or joystic instance to take control of the touch started outside?**

Reading the [Cocos2d documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips%3atouchdelegates) it appears that CCMenu already conforms to the multitouch protocol and hence I should be able to increase its priority. But I am afraid to mess up with this. I tried to change priority of the layer but it crashed.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: You can see what I am describing in various sample projects that I found in various books. Basically whenver someone uses "SneakyJostic" or adds a "CCMenu" on a layer (in any project) if you start the touch from outside the object and move the finger util touching the object it would not detect it. How can I fix this without getting my App to crash?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly want to do but if I dont go in coding part you can extend the touch area of your menu by adding some transparent part of image in your sprite or menu image.
Also for joystick you can also use Guessers for your controller.

Comment: Thanks but I am after a solution using priority. I already added transparent images and I don't find it an elegant solution. I believe there should be a way to do so. To recreate the problem just add a ccmenu or SneakyJoystic to an empty helloworld template and start touching from outside the item. You will see that it won't detect the touch once the finger is above the actual object. The beheaviour I want to achieve is instead to get the item to react once the finger is above.

Comment: I am really sorry because I didn't get what you was upto but on second read I got your question.Did you tried using touchDispatcher as follows-                                                         -(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:kCCMenuTouchPriority swallowsTouches:NO];
}

Comment: Did you try the solution before? It gives me :( " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Layer#ccTouchBegan override me'"

Answer (score 0):

Once the scene starts getting the touch events, it'll get the entire touch movement up to the touchEnded. There's not a 'touchEntered' or 'touchExited' type event that'd be useful here, like you get in some mouse-based systems.

One thing you can try is to have the scene handle the events, perform a hit test, and then forward the event onto the joystick/menu as appropriate (you may be able to simply invoke touchesMoved directly; you might have to synthesize touchBegan/touchEnded events when the finger moves into/out of the joystick/menu area).

Comment: I am not sure this is the most straighforward solution. I thought about something like this as well but have no idea on how to implement it. I think that Cocos2D overcomes this with touch priorities so that's where the solution is for me but haven't yet found it.